# function Wordpress to open image in lightbox

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

implemented lightbox in Wordpress

i have this code , but i need to modified to work ,

http://pastebin.com/hzkc2GwK

The value on   href= doesn't work , i need to open the image in lightbox mode , I use this option for upload a image http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/217/51373696.jpg/

How can do fix this code????

very thanks!!

Comment: This question does harm to humans and animals (my cat is sitting next to me).

Answer (score 0):

[Go Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)

It gives the Codex for working with the WP featured image options